# NonUniqueObjectException in Confluence with scheduled job

Tags: java, hibernate, confluence

Got a huge problem with quartz Job in Confluence, regarding the page creation.

QUARTZ Job class:

```
@ComponentImport
private final SpaceManager spaceManager;
@Autowired
private final GeneralConfig config;
@Autowired
private final PageCreator pageCreator;
@ComponentImport
private final PageManager pageManager;

@Autowired
public ReportingPluginJob(GeneralConfig config, SpaceManager spaceManager, PageCreator pageCreator,
        PageManager pageManager) {
    this.config = config;
    this.spaceManager = spaceManager;
    this.pageCreator = pageCreator;
    this.pageManager = pageManager;
}

private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReportingPluginJob.class);

@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext jec) throws JobExecutionException {

    Collection<String> keys = spaceManager.getAllSpaceKeys(SpaceStatus.CURRENT);

    String parentPageName = config.getSchedulerWeeklyParentPageName();

    for (String key : keys) {

        Page parentPage
                = pageManager.getPage(key, parentPageName);

        if (parentPage != null) {
            LOG.debug("Creating weekly report for space " + key);
            long pageId = parentPage.getId();
            try {
                pageCreator.createEazyBiReport(key, pageId);
            } catch (ApplicationException e) {
                LOG.error("FAILED TO CREATE A REPORT FOR SPACE " + key + " with error: " + System.lineSeparator()
                        + e.getMessage());
            }

        }

    }

}
```

PAGE CREATION class:

```
  Space space = spaceManager.getSpace(spaceKey);

    if (page != null) {
        page.setTitle(pageTitle);
        page.setSpace(space);
        page.setVersion(1);
        page.addLabelling(new Labelling(label, page.getEntity(), AuthenticatedUserThreadLocal.get()));
        page.setCreator(AuthenticatedUserThreadLocal.get());
        page.setCreationDate(new Date());
        Page parent = pageManager.getPage(parentId);
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.addChild(page);
        }
    }
        pageManager.saveContentEntity(page, DefaultSaveContext.builder().suppressNotifications(true).build());
        attachmentProvider.attachExcelFileToPage(page);
```

AND Finally the exception which is driving me mad:

```
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.Space#31653891]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.Space#31653891]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:259)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:362)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:326)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(HibernateTemplate.java:704)
at com.atlassian.confluence.core.persistence.hibernate.HibernateObjectDao.saveRaw(HibernateObjectDao.java:207)
at com.atlassian.confluence.pages.persistence.dao.hibernate.CachingPageDao.saveRaw(CachingPageDao.java:157)
at com.atlassian.confluence.core.DefaultContentEntityManager.saveContentEntity(DefaultContentEntityManager.java:150)
at com.atlassian.confluence.pages.DefaultPageManager.saveContentEntity(DefaultPageManager.java:1388)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2132.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at com.atlassian.spring.interceptors.SpringProfilingInterceptor.invoke(SpringProfilingInterceptor.java:16)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at com.atlassian.confluence.util.profiling.ConfluenceMonitoringMethodInterceptor.invoke(ConfluenceMonitoringMethodInterceptor.java:34)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy105.saveContentEntity(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2132.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.atlassian.plugin.util.ContextClassLoaderSettingInvocationHandler.invoke(ContextClassLoaderSettingInvocationHandler.java:26)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy253.saveContentEntity(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:56)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:60)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invokeUnprivileged(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:70)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invoke(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:53)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:57)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2863.saveContentEntity(Unknown Source)
at com.censored.atlassian.plugins.service.PageCreator.createEazyBiReport(PageCreator.java:128)
at com.censored.atlassian.plugins.service.ReportingPluginJob.execute(ReportingPluginJob.java:64)
at com.atlassian.confluence.plugin.descriptor.JobModuleDescriptor$DelegatingPluginJob.lambda$execute$0(JobModuleDescriptor.java:113)
at com.atlassian.confluence.impl.vcache.VCacheRequestContextManager.doInRequestContextInternal(VCacheRequestContextManager.java:87)
at com.atlassian.confluence.impl.vcache.VCacheRequestContextManager.doInRequestContext(VCacheRequestContextManager.java:71)
at com.atlassian.confluence.plugin.descriptor.JobModuleDescriptor$DelegatingPluginJob.execute(JobModuleDescriptor.java:112)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:223)
at com.atlassian.confluence.schedule.quartz.ConfluenceQuartzThreadPool.lambda$runInThread$0(ConfluenceQuartzThreadPool.java:16)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
```

According the stack trace, I've got a problem during the page save (saveContentEntity). It seems, the page save needs to update a space associated with the page too.
And here comes the problem. According to the stack trace, this space exists in the Hibernate session already. `evict` and `clear` of the actual session does not work.
Any suggestions, how can I handle this exception, or how can I actually remove the space from Hibernate session?

Comment: Can you provide the piece of code where you actually call session.save(), and session.evict()/session.clear(). One more information that I wanted to know was ..  (since you are calling save in a loop) were you able to identify whether exception is thrown during the very first attempt of save or it was able to save some objects prior to the exception thrown?

Comment: Please, provide the entity class.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is what's happening in your code:

1. Within your `SpaceManager`, your session finds a `Session` object with ID 1 (assume that) and returns it.
2. Your method uses this reference to associate with another object, a `Page` one.
3. And finally, your `PageManager` persist this data in the database.

Probably, your problem is problem that:
From step 1 to 2, when the `SpaceManager` returns the data, your transaction is ended and your returned object becomes `detached`.
After that, when  you call `save`, you are trying to persist a detached `Session`, but it already exists in the database. Then you get an exception.

You could try to use the `merge` method or remove the `cascade` from this reference in your entity.

(Please provide your entity code so I can improve my answer if there's anything wrong or which don't work for you.)

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same problem and what solved it for us was to put the code that creates the page (and loads other objects, like the space or the parent page) all into a transaction:

```
private void createNewPage(String title, String pageInput, Long parentPageId, String spaceKey) {
    transactionTemplate.execute(() -> {
        Page page = new Page();
        page.setTitle(title);
        page.setBodyAsString(pageInput);

        Space space = spaceManager.getSpace(spaceKey);
        page.setSpace(space);

        Page parentPage = pageManager.getPage(parentPageId);
        if (parentPage != null) {
            page.setParentPage(parentPage);
            parentPage.addChild(page);
        }

        pageManager.saveContentEntity(page, DefaultSaveContext.DEFAULT);

        return null;
    });
}
```

com.atlassian.sal.api.transaction.TransactionTemplate can be injected with @ComponentImport